# How do I set background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create div element using JQuery using the below code, the elements are getting created correctly but the substitution of background-image attribute is completely broken...

The "/" in the imagepath_start is corrupted, so the background image is not set properly.

```
imagepath_start = "http://webfact.com/online_static/product-images/book/"

$("<div id = product" + i + "left  class = product-cards-left style=background-image:url(  " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + " > </div>").appendTo('#product' + i)
```

Comment: Try surrounding your attribute values with quotes. `style='background-image:url(.....)'`. It looks hideous without them.

Comment: Syntax issues... you need quotes (double or single) around all of the html attributes like `id="..."` `style="..."` etc. Also, you need to close the `background-image: url(...);` with a closing parentheses (the semicolon is optional but I would encourage it for consistency).

Comment: unless obj.image_caption holds a graphic, I don't see where you are asking for any type of image to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes for the HTML attributes, what would cause the element to be rendered incorrectly try adding single quotes for the attribute values:

```
$("<div id='product" + i + "left'  class='product-cards-left' style='background-image:url(  " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + ")'> </div>").appendTo('#product' + i);
```

You were also missing the closing parenthesis in the background-image css

I am considering that you are building the image path correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When creating DOM elements with jQuery, the following is recommended. As you can see it's quite easy to catch a missing apostrophe or quotation, something quite difficult with long strings especially strings within strings:

```
imagepath_start = "http://webfact.com/online_static/product-images/book/";

$("<div/>",{id: "product" + i + "left",  class: "product-cards-left"})
.css("background-image","url(" + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + ")")
.appendTo('#product' + i);
```